# Laravel Update Table Syntax Error

Tags: laravel, sql-update

I think this is just a small problem but I dont seem to find the reason why its a syntax error.. I've been referring to laravel's site already and I'm staring for a while now. (im still newbie. sorry)

It says  FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '('
in LoginController.php (line 134)

Code below

```
public function updateUser(Request $request)
        {
//line 134 is here
           User::('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["address" => "input['users-city']"]);
           User::('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["contact" => "input['users-contact']"]);
           User::('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["email" => "users-email"]);
        }
```

Comment: you can't use session variable like these, use laravel session.

Comment: I've used those session already in my views no syntax error. I refered to laravel's session also.

Comment: Not about the question, but you can combine these 3 statements to 1 because update can handle an array of key value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  User::where('user_id',\Session::get('userSocial')['id'])
        ->update(["address" => $request->users-city]);

  User::where('user_id', \Session::get('userSocial')['userSocial']
        ->update(["contact" => $request->users-contact]);

  User::where('user_id', \Session::get('userSocial')['userSocial']
       ->update(["email" => $request->users-email]);
```

Comment: thanks man! but i had to replace my variables in form and here because of the "-" (dash) like users-email coz it gave me error. I replaced with $request->usersemail. And I went for shorter code by @Maraboc. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is for the `DB` builder :

```
DB::table('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["address" => $request->userscity]);
DB::table('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["contact" => $request->userscontact]);
DB::table('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["email" => $request->usersemail]);
```

You can regroup the updates in one query for optimization purpose :

```
DB::table('users')->where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])
             ->update([
                    "address" => $request->userscity,
                    "contact" => $request->userscontact,
                    "email" => $request->usersemail]
                );
```

Or you can use `Eloquent` :

```
User::where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])
        ->update([
            "address" => $request->userscity,
            "contact" => $request->userscontact,
            "email" => $request->usersemail]
        );
```

Comment: it worked when "email" => "input["users-email"]. but in database it stored "input["users-email"] also. it was recognized as string

Comment: Thanks for the shorter way of updating table! Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
public function updateUser(Request $request){

  User::where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["address" => "input['users-city']"]);

  User::where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["contact" => "input['users-contact']"]);

  User::where('user_id', session('userSocial')['id'])->update(["email" => "users-email"]);
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: does this specify on users table?